# Translating Simpson and Shannon diversity indices?

Tags: phyloseq

So I am trying to compute diversity indices for a dataset I have but the math doesn't work out and I don't really understand how to translate Shannon and/or Simpson diversity indices into something that is understandable. Maybe I got everything wrong, this is certainly a possibility. However, this is what I have up to now:

```
# load libraries
library("phyloseq")
data("GlobalPatterns")

# load data
globp = GlobalPatterns

# compute transformation according to link below
simpson_transformed <- 1/(1-estimate_richness(globp, measures="Simpson"))
shannon_transformed <- exp(estimate_richness(globp, measures="Shannon"))

# print side by side
print(cbind.data.frame(simpson_transformed, shannon_transformed))
```

The **comparing_indices** columns are computed according to what I found [at this link](http://www.loujost.com/Statistics%20and%20Physics/Diversity%20and%20Similarity/Diversity%20of%20a%20single%20community.htm) (italic is mine):

> They *[i.e. the values]* should be converted to effective number of species,
> which are the true diversities. By referring to Table 1 we see that
> species richness is already a true diversity, so the true diversity
> according to this index is 5.000 species. Table 1 shows that the
> Shannon entropy or Shannon-Wiener index is converted to effective
> number of species or true diversity by taking the exponential:
> exp(1.609) is 5.000, so the true diversity according to the Shannon
> entropy is also 5.000 species. The Gini-Simpson index is converted to
> a  true diversity by subtracting it from unity and inverting:
> 1/(1-0.8) = 5.000 species also. So in fact all these indices agree
> that the diversity of this community is 5.000 species.

I also verified how **phyloseq** is computing the indices. I believe the transformation for Shannon should be the same mentioned above. I have doubts about the Simpson, since they refer to the Gini-Simpson index and not the Simpson itself. However, the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/diversity) for **vegan**'s `diversity()` function, which is the function that (I believe) is called by **phyloseq**'s `estimate_richness()` (see [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/phyloseq/versions/1.16.2/topics/estimate_richness)), mention that the Simpson index is returned as `1-D` [which seems to be the Gini-Simpson index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index#Gini%E2%80%93Simpson_index) (see the `1-lambda`). In other words, it looks like the transformation I linked above should be exactly the one that are used in the code I provided. But, I was expecting the same values in the two columns. But they are not there and I wonder why this happens. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to obtain Hill numbers, sometimes called true diversity, and you have different results because you have uneven species frequencies.

`Vegan` calculates Shannon index like:

$$ H' = -\sum_{i=1}^R p_i \ln p_i $$

And Gini-Simpson like:

$$ 1 - \lambda = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^R p_i^2 $$

So the Hill numbers should be:

$$ H1 = exp(H') $$

$$ H2 = 1 / 1 - \lambda $$

With `Phyloseq`:

```
H1 <- 1 / estimate_richness(globp, measures="Simpson")
H2 <- exp(estimate_richness(globp, measures="Shannon")
```

Comment: I do have a question, though...shouldn't H1 and H2 be equal to each other, since we are talking about true diversity? Why is that not the case?

Comment: H1 is equal to H2 for an even species frequency. The text that you cite uses the term "true diversity" or the "effective number of species", which means [Hill numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index#Effective_number_of_species_or_Hill_numbers).

Comment: alright I think I am understanding what you meant. thank you!